# Angular 5 transpiling without support for IE11 (Object.values is not converted)

Tags: angular, webpack, ecmascript-6, angular5

We are noticing that in a service we had a failure to transform Object.values in code like:

```js
myMethod(items = Object.values(this.config)) {
```

so, it would stay that way even when rendered in ie 11... we obviously need to configure the render targets to include ie 11 (ie 11 has Object.keys but no Object.values). How do I do that?

Comment: i guess you need `import 'core-js/es6/object';` just check pollyfils in your project and its probaly commented somwhere in there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need polyfills for core-js/es7/object.js.

- Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors
- Object.values
- Object.entries

Is part of this polyfill.

```
import 'core-js/es7/object';
```